# PHP Undefined variable in Apache error_log

Tags: php

I'm getting a series of:

"Undefined variable: loginError in /Library/WebServer/Documents/clients  . . ."

entries in my Apache error_log which I would like to prevent. I have a simple login.php page which, if there's an error logging in sets the $loginError variable as such:

```
$loginError = '<p class="text-error">Login Error: '. $layouts->getMessage(). ' (' . $layouts->code . ')</p>';
```

If there's no error logging in it does this:

```
$loginError = '';
```

I then output any errors as such:

```
if ($loginError !== '') { //line 112
echo $loginError; /line 113
}
```

I'm getting the entries for the line 112 and 113 noted in my comments above. Anyone tell me how I can prevent the entries appearing? I'm using PHP Version 5.3.6.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its saying you should check it is set before using:

One way is with `isset()`

```
if (isset($loginError) && $loginError !== '') {
  echo $loginError;
}
```

But in your particular case you may as well use `!empty()`

```
if (!empty($loginError)) {
  echo $loginError;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that's just what I was after.

Comment: np, have a look at the [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) man page it is a great little construct.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing the rest of your code. Trace through your logic to make sure that every possible branch initializes `loginError` at some point in its execution. Even better, set it to a default value *before* you go through the logic.